# Compiling LESS Twitter Bootstrap files in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, twitter-bootstrap, less

I downloaded the twitter bootstrap https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

I am trying to compile the less files , but it giving me a NameError

**lessc wells.less test.css**

the error

```
NameError: .border-radius is undefined in /var/www/2.6.0/assets/less/wells.less:13:2
12   border: 1px solid darken(@wellBackground, 7%);
13   .border-radius(@baseBorderRadius);
14   .box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `lessc` command is still working now in v2.3.1, but you should compile the `bootstrap.less` file. That file will compile all the files included in Bootstrap (except the responsive less files). The content from this file is:

```
@import "variables"
@import "scaffolding"
...
@import "hero-unit.less";
```

So something like:

```
lessc ./bootstrap.less > bootstrap.css
```

should work, but I can't assure you anything since the last version that I tested was 2.1.

Anyway, there is some instructions for compiling their code with a makefile or simply using a `less.js` to avoid compiling. You can see the instructions [in the documentation from their official page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/extend.html#compiling) and in the README of the [github project](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap).

Comment: When I compile bootstrap.less to bootstrap.css , inside the bootstrap.css written : lessc: ENOENT, open '/var/www/2.6.0/assets/bootstrap.less'